# How to factor it, by the method of grouping terms.

Tags: factoring

Good day, i have this exercise:

$(t + k)^{3} - t - k$ , and i must factor it.

I try this:

$(t + k)(t^2 -tk + k^2) - (t + k)$

but obviously it is not yet fully factored. The parenthesis that is trinomial, looks like a binomial square, but it is not, since the second term is not $(2 * t * k)$, since if it were, $t$ or $k$ should be $1/2$ and therefore in its roots it would come out $1/4$

I tried to look for help in symbolab, but says it can not be factored anymore.

so, how i can factor it? , The final factoring should be:

$(t + k)(t + k + 1)(t +k -1)$

Comment: `I try this` You got the sign wrong there, $\,-t-k=-(t\color{red}{+}k)\,$.

Comment: yes, now i have two common terms, but I do not know how to continue

Comment: So you have $\,a^3 - a\,$ where $\,a=t+k\,$. Factor out the common term in $\,a^3-a\,$ and see what's left.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**: $$-t-k=-(t+k) $$

Then, use $$a^2-b^2 = (a-b)(a+b)$$

${{{{{{{}}}}}}} $

Comment: why? how ? i cant understand that

Comment: $(t+k)^3 - t - k = (t+k)^3 - (t+k) $. Can you see the common factor here?

Comment: Isn't a difference of square or difference of cubes, i can't see the common factor, help me please

Comment: Before using the second part of my answer you need to factor $(t+k)^3-(t+k) $. I'm sure you can do it if you give it a try. Hint : how would you factor $x^3-x $?

Comment: thanks, finally: $(t+k)((t+k)^{2} + 1)$ that can be: $(t + k)(t + k -1)(t+k+1)$, thanks for square difference !! and the $x^3 - x$

Comment: Small mistake : it's $(t+k)^2 -1$.

Comment: yes i write it fast